# Como o site decolar.com realiza a pesquisa de preços de passagens?

Tags: web-service

Estou pensando em criar alguns serviços para monitorar os preços de passagens de avião e gostaria de saber como o site decolar.com realiza as suas pesquisas. Digo, que tipo de estratégia ele usa, se é algum tipo de request em uma URL específica dos sites ou um robô que vai la no site mesmo e consulta e espera a página carregar com os resultados e lê o HTML e grava os resultados. Alguém saberia me explicar como?

Comment: Não vou responder porque não sei com certeza, mas há alguns anos conheci uma empresa em SP que trabalhava **só** com webservices (WSDL) de empresas aéreas. Por causa disso e outras coisas, eu duvido que empresas sérias usem tais métodos (robô que inspeciona o site). Se as empresas aéreas tem interesse em vender e outras empresas querem vender pra elas, nada mais justo que usar webservices para disponibilizar de forma consistente as informações.

Comment: Trabalhei com comparadores de preços e as estratégias usadas são usar web crawlers ou fazer parcerias onde o parceiro te envia um arquivo, normalmente XML, com as informações sobre o negócio, no caso aqui, passagens, hospedagens e etc.

Comment: Cara na boa, no brasil isso é literalmente uma mafia

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Tem várias empresas que disponibilizam o Webservice: a Gol, a Tourico, a Webjet, a Tam entre outras.

Respondendo sua pergunta, o site decolar.com utiliza o sistema [Amadeus](http://www.amadeus.com) para fazer suas consultas.

Uma solução que eu já utilizei é a [FlightAware API](http://pt.flightaware.com/commercial/flightxml/), mas ela só trabalha com voos internacionais e a licença é paga. Ela utiliza um sistema de buscas baseado em XML.

Outra que pode ajudar é a [Travelport](http://www.travelport.com/Solutions/Developers/Developers) que tem uma área exclusiva para developers com Webinars e suporte gratuitos

Caso nenhuma dessas te ajude, o jeito é tentar contatar as próprias empresas de voo. Vai ter que trabalhar a lábia e tentar pegar contato com alguém de dentro das empresas.

Comment: E lembrando que mesmo se você conseguir a API, pra vender as passagens você precisa ter crédito nas cias. aéreas, o que não é nada fácil!

Comment: Eu trabalhei em uma empresa que atende a Decolar, realmente é uma mafia

Comment: hoje um cliente me procurou para uma consultoria sobre infra para desenvolver uma solução de planejamento de viagens, alguém tem experiência que gostaria de compartilhar via chat?

Answer (score -1):

Existe uma empresa brasileira que disponibliza uma API/webservice de voo, inclusive de passagens com milhas. Se não me engano, tem smiles, latam e azul. O site é http://apidevoos.com.